# Woocommerce custom fields - Select field - how to do a blank placeholder

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

I have created a cutom field in woocommerce general tab just below the price:

```
function woo_add_custom_general_fields() {

  global $woocommerce, $post;

  echo '<div id="wc-after-price">';

     woocommerce_wp_select( 
             array( 
                  'id'      => '_select', 
                  'label'   => __( 'Price Label', 'woocommerce' ), 
                  'options' => array(
                    'blank'         => __( 'Choose one or leave blank', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'Per 50 Words'  => __( 'Price is per 50 words', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'Per 100 Words' => __( 'Price is per 100 words', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'Per Page'      => __( 'Price is per page', 'woocommerce' )
                    )
                 )
      ); 

  echo '</div>';

}
```

My save function is as follows:

```
function woo_add_custom_general_fields_save( $post_id ){

    $woocommerce_select = $_POST['_select'];
    if( !empty( $woocommerce_select ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_select', esc_attr( $woocommerce_select ) );

}
```

Everything is working well when showing the output, but I am struggling to figure out how to NOT SHOW the first option "blank".

The first option in my dropdown `'blank'  => __( 'Choose one or leave blank', 'woocommerce' ),`
is basically just a placeholder. My dropdown selection is not mandatory, so it could be left blank.

Currently, if I leave the dropdown untouched, it'll show "blank" on the output.

How can I achieve to keep this option only as a placeholder and not show any output at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the `value` as an empty string `''` instead of `blank`.

```
function woo_add_custom_general_fields() {

  global $woocommerce, $post;

  echo '<div id="wc-after-price">';

     woocommerce_wp_select( 
             array( 
                  'id'      => '_select', 
                  'label'   => __( 'Price Label', 'woocommerce' ), 
                  'options' => array(
                    ''         => __( 'Choose one or leave blank', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'Per 50 Words'  => __( 'Price is per 50 words', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'Per 100 Words' => __( 'Price is per 100 words', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'Per Page'      => __( 'Price is per page', 'woocommerce' )
                    )
                 )
      ); 

  echo '</div>';

}
```

Comment: In your `save` function make sure you are using `empty()` check and not `isset()` to determine if it is an actual value is passed or not.

Comment: Dhaval many thanks for your help. I have just edited my question and added the save function for you to see. Would you be able to tell me where in there should I add the `empty()` and `isset()` ?

Comment: @JoeBloggs You are already doing this with `if( !empty( $woocommerce_select ) )`.  As `''         => __( 'Choose one or leave blank', 'woocommerce' )` will essentially create an `empty` value for placeholder text which when submitted will be discarded in your above check. So the code should work without any hinges.